# What is the Windows equivalent of 'Audit log cleared' event in Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, audit, logs

Windows has [EventID 1102 "The audit log was cleared"](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=1102). What is the equivalent audit event in Unix/Linux?

If someone has a sample event, and know what audit policy needs to be configured to get this event, please post that too.

Comment: What is "the security/audit log"?

Comment: Are you looking for a definition for security/audit log?

Comment: No, your question seems to imply that there is only one such log.

Comment: Windows refers to all the logs in event viewer as 'Audit Log'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's none: the audit log is a text-file which can be deleted.  However if auditd is configured to run from the initial boot-up, auditd cannot be stopped, and will continue writing to its open file-descriptor.  That would record the deletion if auditd were configured to watch its output log (though you'd have to recover the file to see the information).

Normally (on end-user systems), auditd is configured to record "security events" (login/logout), but can be told to watch files for changes.  There's nothing specific to (for example) `/var/log/audit/auditd.log`, but you can establish a *watch* for it as documented in the manual page.

Further reading:

- [Linux audit files to see who made changes to a file](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html)